# Множественное объединение mysql

Tags: mysql, join

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше производить объединение с большим количеством столбцов? Писать длинный LEFT JOIN?
Таблицы, начинающиеся с "list_" имеют следующую структуру:

> id | name |

В таблице с приметами_лиц хранятся идентификаторы примет

Answer (score 1):

Вот даже сразу не знаю, что предложить в такой ситуации. С точки зрения НФ структура базы вроде как правильная, но работать с таким ворохом таблиц и ссылок ...

Да, при текущей структуре, единственный вариант - куча LEFT JOIN базовой таблицы с каждой из list_.

Кроме того, если вдруг вам захочется добавить еще какую то примету, то вам надо будет создавать новую таблицу list_, добавлять новую колонку, переделывать все sql-запросы.

Можно переделать структуру базы в такую:

Типы примет

```
   create table ftypes(
     id number,
     name varchar(100)
   )
```

Черты лица

```
  create table features(
    id number, -- ID конкретной черты (голубые, карие, ...)
    ftype_id number, -- ID типа черты лица (глаза, уши, ...
    name varchar(100) -- Название конкретной черты
  )
```

Черты конкретных людей

```
  create table personFeat(
    person_id number,
    ftype_id number,
    feature_id number
  )
  primary key(person_id,ftype_id)
```

Вот последняя таблица конечно кривовата чуть чуть, ftype_id там с одной стороны избыточен, потому как по feature_id он находится, с другой стороны, он нужен для обеспечения уникальности конкретной черты для человека, что бы не было одновременно карих и голубых и зеленых глаз у одного человека

После этого можно писать один left_join, но будет получено много записей и их возможно надо будет разворачивать по горизонтали, что в одном sql запросе весьма нетривиально. С другой стороны, если эти записи отдаются на клиента БД, то он сам уже может разместить их в нужные поля на экране или куда нибудь еще.

По скорости работы ... в принципе БД не особо любят такие таблицы как я предложил, с другой, подклейка десятка таблиц в одном запросе то же тормоза ...